# undefined output while printing object in console

Tags: javascript, object

Suppose i have a object with properties and method.

When i assign `this` object to another object, and i execute following code. Its giving me *undefined undefined* output while printing object `obj1` in console, can anyone please help me on this, and explain me this behaviour.

thank you.

```js
var emp = {
  fname: "sachin",
  lname: "pawar",
  getname: function() {
    return this.fname + " " + this.lname;
  }
};
var obj = emp.getname;
var obj1 = obj();
var obj3 = emp.getname();
console.log(obj1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that *this* in your *getname* method is undefined when called via the line:

```
var obj1 = obj();
```

In JavaScript *this* is dependent upon the context in which the function is called. So, when you call it as a 'dot method' against the emp object *this* refers to its containing object. Where you call it 'stand alone' it has no contect and *this* is undefined.

You can bind a standalone call to give it a context, as follows:

```
var obj=emp.getname.bind(emp);
var obj1=obj();
```

Then when it executes it will use *emp* to get its context for *this*.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `obj = emp.getname`, its reference is copied and when you call it, there is a difference in `obj.function()` and `function()`.

When you do `obj.function`, function's `this` is set as `obj`, but when you copy reference and call it, since no object is associated to this call, it takes global scope(`window`). Hence it returns `undefined`.

#### Sample

```js
window.fname = "Foo";
window.lname = "Bar";
var emp = {
  fname: "sachin",
  lname: "pawar",
  getname: function() {
    return this.fname + " " + this.lname;
  }
};
var obj = emp.getname;
var obj1 = obj();
var obj3 = emp.getname();
console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj3);
```

#### Alternate implementation

```js
var emp = (function() {
  // private properties
  var fname = "sachin"
  var lname = "pawar"
  var getname = function() {
    return fname + " " + lname;
  }
  // Selected properties exposed
  return {
    getname: getname
  }
})()

var obj = emp.getname;
var obj1 = obj();
var obj3 = emp.getname();
console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj3);
```